# How to fill a matrix using elements from another?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix:

```
A = [1;2;3;4];
```

I would like to create another matrix B of size 20*1 from A. How can I implement that effectively? Elements can be repeated and should be picked in random order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) for that, for your example:

```
B = randi(4,20,1)
```

For the general case where A has other values and other sizes, use indexing:

```
B = A(randi(numel(A),20,1))
```

Answer (score 3):

For the general case, where the elements of A can take any value, you can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) (you can even set different probabilities for each element).

```
B = randsample(A(:),20);
```